# How to detect where NaN is passing to CoreGraphics API on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, osx-mavericks

I have very large graphic Mac app and now I receive a lot of the following messages in Console on 10.9 GM.

```
<Error>: Error: this application, or a library it uses, has passed an invalid numeric value (NaN, or not-a-number) to CoreGraphics API. This is a serious error and contributes to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.
```

I noticed that these messages appear in debugger after calling [NSApp nextEventMatchingMask: untilDate inMode: dequeue] but I think the reasons are in some other places. But I have too many places where I use Cocoa Graphics. I didn't receive this kind of message before 10.9.

How to detect where NaN is passing to CoreGraphics API?

[image: Screenshot for this error on console]

Comment: You need to expand your stack traces a little more.  The event dispatch mechanism is a top-level function of the run loop, not the graphics stack.

Comment: These messages appear in console immediately after step over  nextEventMatchingMask:. It seems, error events accumulated somewhere and then are shown together. How to expand graphics stack?

Comment: There's a slider at the bottom of the stack trace pane.  Slide it as far to the right as it goes, then see which function appears at the top of the trace.

Comment: Nothing appears at the top of the stack except my current function. Other threads also don't have something relative to core graphics. Just error messages appear in console window.

Comment: I'm getting this error in console window for code running on Xcode 7.1.1 and OS X 10.11.1. What's the fix?

Comment: In my case, setting another view controller to an existing NSPopover instance caused this error.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

After much digging around, I've found you can set a symbolic breakpoint on "CGPostError" in Xcode, and that will give you a stack trace.

Comment: THIS IS A MINDBLOWING TIP.

Comment: incredible tip.

Comment: I no longer get the error with this symbolic breakpoint active.

Comment: I got a app stopped for this breakpoint, but nothing shown in the Debug navigator, but adding `CG_NUMERICS_SHOW_BACKTRACE` helped me to print the stacktrace of the problem.

Answer (score 13):

The habit of creating lazy `UIView`'s with a `.zero` frame played against me when doing it for a `PDFView`.

This

```
var pdfView = PDFView(frame: .zero)
```

will generate lots of the same logs from the question. The reason I used `.zero`, is because later I set up the view with constraints. This proved to be a problem. The solution was to use an arbitrary, non-zero frame when initializing the `PDFView`.

```
var pdfView = PDFView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
```

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH FOR THIIIIISSSS!!!!!!! ❤️

Answer (score 7):

I was getting this error when I was foolishly retaining an NSPopover for future use.

It seems `popover.showRelativeToRect(_:)` is all you need to do, and then you can forget about it.

Comment: Hi Chris, can you please explain how to resolve that issue in objective c

Comment: In my case I was storing an NSPopover reference in a static var to share among a number of view objects. It looks as if NSPopover doesn't like being reused once it has been shown. Recreating the popover on demand, though not ideal, did quite the warning. Breaking on CGPostError shows that the error is generated in NSPopover -showRelativeToRect:preferredEdge:

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It's dividing by zero at some point that leads to NSAffineTransform with NaN elements in the matrix. For some reasons compiler and OS passed this situation before 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

so you should get an exception at that point, so an exception breakpoint should work...

here are things to look out for...

you may have messed up a method signature... ie

```
-(float)myHeight
{
    return 56.0;
}
```

gets messed up in a subclass

```
-(int)myHeight
{
    return 42;
}
```

or you have some bad math(s) that emit a NaN...

there are a couple of ways to detect a NaN... 
c99 introduced `isnan()`
also the ieee float trick of `(f != f)` will be true for NaN

Comment: Is this actually an exception? AFAIK, it's not—neither Objective-C nor C++. You used to be able to set a breakpoint on `CGError`, although I remember that being explicitly mentioned in Quartz's error messages (but I never had this specific error before). (Users of AppCode: It doesn't support symbolic breakpoints as of 2.1—you'll have to use Xcode for this.)

Comment: yeah I don't really know if it is an exception at this point, I haven't done iOS development in a long time... @PeterHosey in appcode do you get access to the raw gdb/lldb prompt? if so you can set a symbolic breakpoint... you could in xcode even set one with a condition of f!=f (I imagine, but haven't tested)

Comment: In AppCode, there is a debugger console pane, but half the time it doesn't work (prompt never appears). I don't know what you mean by “a condition of `f!=f`”.

Comment: @PeterHosey in Xcode you can set a conditional breakpoint, which I am sure you are aware... but the condition being for some float f, f!=f (itself) is only true for NaN

Comment: Oh, right. The potential NaN would need to be in scope, though. If it's getting NaN'd within CG or Foundation code, that limits where you can use that.

Comment: yeah and you would have to assign it to variable... wouldn't likely be easy to find... probabl{'/