# Converting NSString which was read from a file to NSURL to create AVAsset in Swift

Tags: swift, nsurl, avasset

At Obj-C we were reading a file and converting its NSString content to NSURL to get AVAsset which was saved as absoluteString beforehand.

```
audioAssetURL  = [NSURL URLWithString:[readNSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

audioAsset      = [AVAsset assetWithURL: audioAssetURL];
```

But In Swift once again saved NSURL as absoluteString can not be used as NSURL and creates error.

```
let urlString: NSString = readNSString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)! 

let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlString as String)

audioAsset = AVAsset(URL: url )as AVAsset
```

The error message we are getting is that "Error: this application, or a library it uses, has passed an invalid numeric value (NaN, or not-a-number) to CoreGraphics API and this value is being ignored.Please fix this problem."

Comment: It looks that somewhere in your code you are dividing by zero.

You can try to set a symbolic breakpoint on `CGPostError` for easier debugging.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187344/how-to-detect-where-nan-is-passing-to-coregraphics-api-on-mac-os-x-10-9

Comment: When      audioAsset = AVAsset(URL: url ) as AVAsset       has been erased we are not getting error message.

Comment: @Hope this cast as AVAsset makes no sense also

Comment: Creating urlString as NSString to later cast it back to String makes no sense either

Comment: _url_ was kept in a file as **NSSTRING** so to recreate audioAsset when application reopened we got to convert it. At Obj-C it was working without problem as I wrote in my question.