# PDF view - view not showing unless zoom is out

Tags: pdf, swiftui, pdfkit, pinchzoom, pdfview

I'm working on a swiftUI app where I have to display multiple PDF files in one screen.
I've created a PDFView:

```html
struct PDFKitRepresentedView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL

    init(_ url: URL) {
        self.url = url
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) -> PDFKitRepresentedView.UIViewType {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: self.url)
        pdfView.document = pdfDocument
        return pdfView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PDFKitRepresentedView>) {
        // Update the view.
    }
}

struct PDFKitView: View {
    var url: URL

    var body: some View {
        PDFKitRepresentedView(url)
    }
}
```

The PDF is created here:

```html
if let url = attachment.path {
                PDFKitView(url: url)
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth - 40, height: UIScreen.screenHeight - 40, alignment: .center)
                    .padding()
            }
```

The problem I'm having is that, whenever the first document is multipage, in order to see the other documents the user has first to pinch to zoom out completely and the other PDF's are shown in sequence.

I've tried to add this values, but that just makes the content of the PDF to disappear

[image]

I was wondering if setting the frame on the PDFKitView directly could be causing the issue, but no.
Anyone has any suggestions on how to make this work? I assume that if I could make the pdf to show already with a min zoom it would display the view correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer on this post [How to detect where NaN is passing to CoreGraphics API on Mac OS X 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187344/how-to-detect-where-nan-is-passing-to-coregraphics-api-on-mac-os-x-10-9)

[image]